# How to decrease loss and increase accuracy in a random data experiment?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I just step into the world of  Deep learning and made some little experiment to learn how to adjust the model to decrease loss and increase accuracy,
No matter how many methods I tried (add layers, neuron etc..)
but still not reach reach my goal...
could any one can give me some tip and suggestion?
thanks!

note: because I made a very big and ugly model before, and the data couldn't fit the model(ie: accuracy no increase), so just made a little and easy test to learning how to adjust model,
btw in this model, my data very similar this little experiment data(stock market data, very stochastic), so try to use this data to learn more...thanks!

here is my code, it is very simple:

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

x1 = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(100, 2)*100,0))
y1 = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(100, 1)*100,0))
scale = StandardScaler() #z-scaler物件
xx1 = pd.DataFrame(scale.fit_transform(x1), columns=x1.keys())
yy1 = pd.DataFrame(scale.fit_transform(y1), columns=y1.keys())
the_input =  keras.Input(shape=(2))
x = layers.Dense(500)(the_input)
for i in range(50):
    x = layers.Dense(500, activation='linear')(x)
    if i%5 ==0 : x = layers.LayerNormalization(axis=1)(x)

main_output_1 = layers.Dense(1, name='mo_1')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=the_input, outputs=main_output_1, name='DELS_model')
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Several ways we can improve the model accuracy one way by tuning hyperparamaters such as batch_size, epochs, leaning rate, activation function, regularization and early stopping technique. Thanks!